# How to reload a part of web page using ajax

Tags: ajax, reload

I am trying to refresh the image part of the webpage after upload the image.

But not get success.

I need your help.

plz help me in reload the webpage using ajax.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We need some more information on what you have tried to do. code, html.

Answer (score 0):

This code shows the ALERTS - before image loading and after image loaded.
You can process you data wherever you want using this.

`$(document).ready(function(){`

```
    function imageLoaded() {
    // function to invoke for loaded image
       alert("image loaded......");
    }
    $('img').each(function() {
      alert("image loading......");
      if( this.complete ) {
         imageLoaded.call( this );
      } else {
         $(this).one('load', imageLoaded);
      }
     });
```

});